# Is there any small linux distribution which comes with a complete C development environment

Tags: linux, c

I have installed "Damn Small Linux" on my home computer for doing  C development in unix. But the distribution doesn't by default come with the C development environment and I am facing some issues when trying to install the gcc.

Is there any other small Linux distribution which by default has the required packages for the C development. And also I don't want additional software which takes up lot of space but  still would like to have the graphical environment.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please define you meaning of "SMALL"?

Comment: Those on superuser might not understand a complete C development environment.

Answer (score 1):

You could start from [Ubuntu JEOS](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/jeos) (Just Enough Operating System) and then install/configure `xfce4` (as WM for example) and gcc (`build-essential`) via apt-get (basically benefit from the great repositories Ubuntu has).

Comment: I'm pretty sure its `build-essential` ... (no s on the end)

Comment: Good point, updated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can not think of a distribution that ships with a complete tool chain. This is for a few reasons:

1. Not everyone wants to compile programs. Compiler + binutils + headers + debuggers take up room that many people would rather use for other things.
2. Saves bandwidth. Sure, an ISO is an ISO, but when people update / upgrade, they'll tend to pull in more updates.
3. Some people view the presence of a compiler as a security risk in certain settings.

No distribution is going to 'please everyone' , however not including a tool chain is a compromise to please as many people as possible.

I build Ubuntu in a very strange way (well, not really strange, just overly pedantic regarding what I install).

I start with `debootstrap` to get the core utilities installed, then I `chroot` to the installation and install the stuff that I want. Usually this is:

1. `build-essential`
2. `kubuntu-desktop`
3. (a long list of libraries with development header packages)

You could substitute `kubuntu-desktop` for:

```
edubuntu-desktop - educational desktop for Ubuntu
edubuntu-desktop-kde - educational desktop for Kubuntu
ubuntu-desktop - The Ubuntu desktop system
xubuntu-desktop - Xubuntu desktop system
```

I then grab the kernel I want from kernel.org and configure/build/install it.

I can then copy over my newly populated root file system to a logical volume and boot to it, or partition a new drive and copy everything over, then chuck the drive into the new system.

Why, oh why do I spend so much time doing this? I'm anal retentive regarding what I install and use .. and I get a great deal of satisfaction out of using something that I put together myself.

After booting, I install anything else that I may need, as I find a need for it. I also uninstall anything I know that I'm never going to use.

Anyway, the result is a system that should fit *your* needs very well, which is how it should be :)

Comment: Every source distribution (like Gentoo etc.) comes per defintion with a _complete_ toolchain. But Gentoo is not after everybodies liking, but ir could probably be configured to be very small.

Comment: @drhirsch - That should probably be an answer, once expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Damn Small Linux comes with [`tcc`](http://bellard.org/tcc/) (see [the package list](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/packages.html)), which is indeed a standards-compliant compiler.  I don't know exactly what libraries you're missing, but it should have at least the standard C libraries available.

Comment: It is not right, I have installed damn_small_linux 2024 version. It has no built-in gcc compiler, no tcc, no compiler at all.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal install of Debian isn't really very big (although not as small as Damn Small Linux), and you can easily add a compile environment to that (just add the `gcc`, `make` and `libc6-dev` packages).

Answer (score 0):

[ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) with some lightweight DE and gcc should meet your requirements.

Comment: Arch has a 'base-devel' package which includes software for building but not for developing applications I fear (i.e. no gdb etc.).

Comment: Of course: for anything else will be as simple as writing 'sudo pacman -S gcc gdb' or whatelse.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you COULD start with Debian Linux and their "netinst" CD, and then just add the pieces you need. http://www.debian.org/distrib/netinst#smallcd

If you're careful you can keep it small (VERY small if you don't need the graphical environment).  Most folks would want a GUI and if so you'll need X-11, but you can choose a lightweight window manager instead of KDE or Gnome.  It's all relatively painless if you have a broadband connection.